# How to validate email in JS?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I need to validate this email using JS, I need to check for the @sign and a period. This is what I have now, but if I run all my code it doesn't not validate the @ sign.

```
if(email.value == "" || !isNaN(email.value) ) {
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
        //something is wrong.
       isValid = false;
       txtFeedback.innerHTML += "<p>Please enter a valid email address.</p>";
        email.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "Please enter a email address.";
   }
```

Comment: view this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this `regex`

```
var regex = /^([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,14}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
regex.test(email); // true if valid email
```

Comment: Fails on valid e-mail addresses (for TLD's that have more than 6 characters).

Comment: Could you provide me with the sample that failed?

Comment: [`registrars@nic.amsterdam`](http://nic.amsterdam/#newsletter). Also any address with a `+` in the name (which is also valid).

Comment: @robertklep I updated the regex; how about now?

Comment: Nope, it won't accept `{}` in the name, which is also valid. And `"hello world"@some.domain` is also valid ([check](http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~pdw/cgi-bin/emailvalidate)). E-mail address validation is _not_ trivial.